# Rails association there is a way to update third "many to many" table?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, rails-activerecord, has-many-through, has-and-belongs-to-many

How to create a chain of two tables (build two new rows through two different many to many)

```
Zombies -> Organs -> Body_parts

Zobmies -> Recovery_tools -> Tools_impacts -> Body_parts
```

The association:

```
class Zombie < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :organs
 has_many :Body_parts, through: :organs
 has_many :Recovery_tools, dependent: :destroy

class Organ < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :Zombie
 belongs_to :Body_part

class BodyPart < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :zombies
  belongs_to :zombies
  has_many :organs
  has_many :zombies, through: organs,  dependent: :destroy

class RecoveryTool < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :zombies
  has_many :Body_parts, :through => :tools_impacts
  has_many :tools_impacts, dependent: :destroy 
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :tools_impacts, :allow_destroy => true 

class ToolsImpact < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :Recovery_tools
 belongs_to :Body_parts
```

I need if the Zombie updates\creates tools_impacts also update\create organs (with Zombie_id and body_part_id)

I think that am able to do it separately, like so:

```
 @Recovery_tools = @zombie.Recovery_tools.build(Recovery_tools_params)
 if @Recovery_tools.save
    @zombie.organs.build(Recovery_tools_id)
```

but I would like to know if there is a way to do this at once, together.
Or any other more correct way to do it.
Thanks.

Comment: You shouldn't be using CamelCase for your association names; you should use snake case.